# How to seperate a html file which is in the static folder to different route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'templates')));

app.get('login/dashboard.html', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/index.html');
});
```

I want to access the dashboard.html file which is in templates/login/ from app.get not from app.use.
How can I do it?

Comment: Try going to `localhost:yourport/login/dashboard.html`, it should work fine

Comment: Yes I do get access it there but I dont want it to load I want to acess it from the app.get method

Comment: Remove the `app.get('login....` because this GET request already gets handled, rn you're just redirecting requests for the dashboard.html file to your main html file or your index.html file

Comment: Yes I can do that but I want to run some code when users get in dashboard.html not in otherpages as get request how can I do it, that is my question, sorry for being unclear

Comment: Ok, try doing `app.get("/login/dashboard.html", (req, res) ...)` note the `/` in front